# property view not found no object of type secondViewController

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

secondViewController.h  :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

viewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize secondViewController;

- (IBAction)switchView:(id)sender{
    [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

property view not found no object of type secondViewController 
what's the trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)switchView:(id)sender{
secondViewController *second = [[secondViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:second.view atIndex:0];
}
```

Also, delete that `@synthesize secondViewController;`.

Comment: i build a xib file  initWithNibName